# How to get name when roll number is given in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

My code is:

```
df=pd.read_excel('vip.xlsx')
df
b=df['Roll No']
a=[x for x in  map(str,b) if x[:8] == '12153162'] 
d=df['Name']
c=[y for y in map(str,d)]
if a in df['Roll No']:
    print(df['Name'])
```

I got a type error for this:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

For example my data frame is:

```
Name          Roll No
Rahil         1215316235
Meher         1210316934
Sreejan       1215316235
Aditya        1215316952
Ajith         1215316002
```

For this data frame my expected output for my above code is:

```
 Rahil
 Sreejan
```

So how do i get my expected output for my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with convert values to strings by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and selecting first 8 valeus by indexing:

```
s = df.loc[df['Roll No'].astype(str).str[:8] == '12153162', 'Name']
print (s)
0      Rahil
2    Sreejan
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

---

```
df1 = df[df['Roll No'].astype(str).str[:8] == '12153162']
print (df1)
      Name     Roll No
0    Rahil  1215316235
2  Sreejan  1215316235
```

If want use list comprehension for filtering:

```
s = df.loc[[str(x)[:8] == '12153162' for x in df['Roll No']], 'Name']
print (s)

0      Rahil
2    Sreejan
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the exception is thrown on this line:

```
if a in df['Roll No']:
```

'a' is a list (mutable type), and keys must be immutable.

Instead, you can make the selection by using 'isin' method:

```
names = df['Name'][df['Roll No'].isin(a)]
print(names)
```

Comment: I'm Getting an empty series.

Comment: The selection should be df['Roll No'].isin(a), instead of df['Name'].isin(a). I corrected the answer.